# Unpermitted parameter: address_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to create nested attributes but I'm getting the following error `"Unpermitted parameter: address_fields"` the fields appear when I'm trying to generate and create a new nested address but doesn't get saved.

In controller :

```
def praject_params
  params.require(:praject).permit(:name, :cpf, :phone, :email, :zip, :city, :state, :borough, :street, :number, :comp, :type, address_attributes: [ :id, :ziptwo, :citytwo, :statetwo, :boroughtwo, :streetwo, :numbertwo, :comptwo, :typetwo])
end
```

In address model :

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :foo
  belongs_to :praject, optional: true
end
```

In praject model :

```
class Praject < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :foo
  has_many :addresses, inverse_of: :praject, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |att| att['name'].blank?}
  before_save do
    self.type.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("type")
  end
end
```

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :ziptwo
      t.string :citytwo
      t.string :statetwo
      t.string :boroughtwo
      t.string :streetwo
      t.string :numbertwo
      t.string :comptwo
      t.string :typetwo
      t.belongs_to :praject, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In the `_form.html.erb` I just have a button to add a new nested address field. 
The funny part is that this error appear in the console when the rails application is running and I'm trying to create a new project, I tried to change the controller to addresses_attributes[] and is not working too. Can anyone help me? I'm getting crazy with this, I tried almost everything and nothing works.

```
## _form.html.erb

<%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <th>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, label: 'Name' %>
      <%= f.input :cpf, label: 'Cpf' %>
      <%= f.input :phone, label: 'Phone' %>
      <%= f.input :email, label: 'Email' %>
      <%= f.input :zip, label: 'Zip' %>
      <%= f.input :city, label: 'City' %>
      <%= f.input :state, label: 'State' %>
      <%= f.input :borough, label: 'Neighbourhood' %>
      <%= f.input :street, label: 'Street' %>
      <%= f.input :number, label: 'Number' %>
      <%= f.input :comp, label: 'Comp' %>
      <div class="field">
        <h4>Type:</h4>

        <%= label_tag 'type_comer', 'Comercial' %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'praject[type][]', 'comercial', checked('comercial'), id: 'type_comer' %>

        <%= label_tag 'type_res', 'Residential' %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'praject[type][]', 'Residential', checked('Residencial'), id: 'type_res' %>

        <%= label_tag 'type_farm', 'Rural' %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'praject[type][]', 'Rural', checked('Rural'), id: 'type_farm' %>

        <%= label_tag 'type_beach', 'Beach' %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'praject[type][]', 'Beach', checked('Beach'), id: 'type_beach' %>

      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Secondary Addresses:</h3>
  </th>
<div class="field"
```

Comment: What's in your form? That's where params are generated.

Comment: Your form.html file is the culprit. You are sending something from form called `address_fields` which you are not permitting in controller. Please share the code of the form view of `praject`.

Comment: Should be `addresses_attributes` instead of `address_attributes` in the `praject_params`?

Comment: I posted the _form.html.erb down in the question. I already tried to change to addresses_attributes and still the same.

Comment: Don't post edits to your questions as answers. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for(@praject) do |f| %>
   # ...
  <%= f.fields_for(:addresses) do |address| %>
    <%= address.input :cpf, label: 'Cpf' %>
    <%= address.input :phone, label: 'Phone' %>
    <%= address.input :email, label: 'Email' %>
    <%= address.input :zip, label: 'Zip' %>
    <%= address.input :city, label: 'City' %>
    <%= address.input :state, label: 'State' %>
    <%= address.input :borough, label: 'Neighbourhood' %>
    <%= address.input :street, label: 'Street' %>
    <%= address.input :number, label: 'Number' %>
    <%= address.input :comp, label: 'Comp' %>
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

If you are using simple_form use its wrapped `simple_fields_for` method instead.

Comment: PS. why are you spelling it praject instead of project?

Comment: To avoid conflicts with another project. But I found the problem, It was on the Ruby/Rails version.